# Angular consumes express web api , bad request

Tags: node.js, angular

My angular app consumes a nodejs webapi :

```
var header = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders()
          .set('Authorization',  `Bearer ${this.token}`)
      }


      var url="http://localhost:3000/user/deleteTodoFromUser/"+idUser+"/"+idTodo;
      return this.http.put(url,"",header);
```

my api :

```
**router.put('/deleteTodoFromUser/:id/:idTodo', passport.authenticate('bearer'), (req, res) => {**

 User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id,{ $pull:{todos:{$in:[req.params.idTodo]}}},{new:true},(err, usr) => {
       if (err) { 
            res.send(err);
        } 
        if(usr)
        {
        res.send(usr);
        }
        else
        {
            res.status(400).send("bad request");
        }
```

**My api works properly in postman **

** CORS are enabled **

in angular doesn't, it returns 400 (bad request )

```
let params = new HttpParams();
params = params.append('id', idUser);
params = params.append('idTodo', idTodo);

this.http.put(url, "", { headers: headers, params: params });
```

when I add params parameter in the request , It becomes like that

```
http://localhost:3000/user/deleteTodoFromUser/?id=5dfa958e98710030207952cc&idTodo=5dfa976ea4ea1d31f8919ee5
```

but the api waits the request like that :

```
http://localhost:3000/user/deleteTodoFromUser/5dfa958e98710030207952cc/5dfa976ea4ea1d31f8919ee5
```

**the difference is my api waits the request id without id?= and idTodo?=** 
and I want it like that

Comment: check your browser console and see if there is a CROS error

Comment: cors middleware are used in nodejs and they work , I have two other api and they are working properly I have an issue with this one

Comment: can you check what is in there for req.params and also check whether record exists in DB, as per your code, if usr not exists, you are returning 400 , so it is showing bad request

Comment: the usr I use is the user connected so it exists and idTodo also exists , the same url when I test it in postman with same parameter works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

400 Bad Request, Whatever the endpoint is expecting, it's not getting it.
Seems that there is an issue while passing params to your API or the token value sent to your API is invalid.

This is another way to send parameters to your API instead of Appending them to the URL

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders()
          .set('Authorization',  `Bearer ${this.token}`);

let params = new HttpParams();
params = params.append('id', idUser);
params = params.append('idTodo', idTodo);

this.http.put(url, "", { headers: headers, params: params });
```

If it's not the case try to make a call using real parameters value and a valid token that works in Postman in order to detect the root cause of the error that you are getting.

Comment: I tried it , the url will be like that : 

localhost:3000/user/deleteTodoFromUser?id=5dfa958e98710030207952cc&idTodo=5dfa976ea4ea1d31f8919ee5







** but the api  expect it without id and idtodo in the parameter like that :**

` localhost:3000/user/deleteTodoFromUser/5dfa958e98710030207952cc/5dfa976ea4ea1d31f8919ee5 `

Comment: Did you still getting 400 Bad request error ? if it's the case try to test with static values like using directly the url that you sent in your comment: localhost:3000/user/deleteTodoFromUser/5dfa958e98710030207952cc/5dfa976ea4ea1d31f8919ee5 just to see if you will get the same behaviour

Comment: in postman everything works fine , the problem is when I use the header for authorization I think the request waits for parameter that's why it returns bad request . When I remove the headers It works fine localhost:3000/user/deleteTodoFromUser/5dfa958e98710030207952cc/5dfa976ea4ea1d31f8919ee5 

but I need to use the header authorization

Comment: why do you have to add authorization header if you can already access to your api without token ?

Comment: No , I remove it both in angular and in api to test

Comment: could you replace ${this.token} with a real token value that works in postman ? and see if the token is sent to your api ?

Comment: Thank you bro , the problem was in the token . the token had a wrong value . 
answer the question so I can mark it as accepted .

Comment: Glad to hear that. you are welcome, i updated my answer so that it could be helpful for others.